# If I leave something/drop it on the ground, how long will it stay there until it unspawns?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

If I would like to leave breadcrumbs behind in one of the mazes, I'm wondering: will the items I use as breadcrumbs unspawn at some point?

For example, in Minecraft, if you leave something on the ground, I think it will disappear in 5 minutes; is a similar system in Breath of the Wild?

Comment: I think you should be fine in the context of doing this within a maze but I haven't any evidence to back this up, only a hunch.

Comment: lol, I was just watching a Game Grumps episode in which he tries this. He comes back a few minutes later an there's nothing there; so I guess there's an unspawn mechanic. Now just to know how the mechanic works. is it Distance, Time, combination of both?

Comment: I haven't tried the mazes yet, so I don't know what the particular problems to over come are, but could you not use stamps or pins on the map for the same effect?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As far as I can tell from my testing, items will stay on the ground indefinitely as long as you're close by. They only despawn when you're a significant distance away.

As a test, I dropped an item on the ground in a safe area (a stable), then left the game running while I made myself some lunch. When I came back about ten minutes later, the item was still right next to me. This is evidence that there is no time limit for items despawning.

Another time I killed a Hinox which dropped some strong royal weapons. At the time, I could not carry any more weapons, so I walked a few hundred feet to kill a nearby Lynel. After killing the Lynel, I went back to where the royal weapons had been, but they were nowhere to be found. This shows that distance affects when items despawn. However I have not done any tests for how far you need to go before that happens.

Though the breadcrumb idea is clever for navigation, I suspect the mazes are a little too big and that items will begin to despawn as you traverse the narrow corridors, which may get you even more lost than you started.

Comment: So I guess its distance based.

Comment: I heard in a YouTube video that the distance appears to be what you can see in the mini-map in the bottom right-hand corner of your screen. If you item is on a part of the map no longer visible in the mini-map, it disappears.

Comment: I can confirm this, sort of. I was deforesting an area for wood and moved a little away to kill an enemy and retrieve what it dropped, when I turned around the whole forest had regrown. So I assume dropped items would disappear too, and the distance required is fairly small.

Comment: I'm not so sure it's completely distance based. I remember instances where I take out an enemy using arrows, then others nearby come to attack me. After finishing those guys off, I move in to claim my prize and none of the items that enemy would usually drop weren't there. Other cases where I kill one thing up close, then move away killing others along the way (not too far, but a lot of them). Coming back to the first there's nothing.

Comment: It's probably a mix between the item's distance to you, how long it's been on the ground, and what item type it is. For example, when you shoot one of the dragons, their shards fly off quite far sometimes, yet you can still pick them up 5 minutes later even if you're moderately far away from them. Meanwhile, arrows seem to vanish after stepping a hundred feet away. Generally speaking, though, I think distance is the biggest factor.

Comment: There appears to be a limit to how many items can be on the ground, as well. I don't have a specific number, but I was in a shrine lining up all my weapons on the ground so I could take pics of them all for the compendium, and as I laid down the last weapon, I went back to the start of the line and found that some of the weapons had disappeared.

Comment: Yeah, I've noticed sometimes when fighting a lot of enemies (around a skull for example) that the more common items enemies drop seem to disappear, so horns and teeth might vanish while guts remain, if you take to long to get back to them.

Comment: @MageXy For the Dragon parts (and Shooting Stars) the items that fly off aren't actually dropped on the ground they seem to just be some sort of marker without any model or physics applied. If you watch the items you can actually see them switch to the dropped item as you start to get closer. This actually screwed me over once as a star fell onto a slight slope, and when I got near enough for it to switch it then started sliding down the hill and off a cliff. I chased after it but was unable to pick it up before it despawned due to sun up. :(

Comment: @Malco I know that's true for stars, but I think the dragon parts are items as soon as they hit the ground. I've seen them land on the sides of mountains very far away and then start falling down immediately, even though I was a good two minutes walk from their location.

Comment: @MageXy Hmm I might be mistaken then. I was pretty sure the dragon drops acted the same way as stars, but it has been a while since I have farmed them.

Comment: There might be also in the factors the number of items that are present with physics in the world right now, would explain the thing of  the swords and the guts.

Answer (score 1):

I found that there's an item limit also, as a joke, I dropped a bunch of rare stuff to "leave it there" (I was with friends) but when I dropped my 4 lynel guts, 5 giant ancient cores, and 7 ancient cores, the lynel guts all despawned and 2 of the giant ancient cores did too (I immediately picked them up)

Note: I did this in the southern oasis in the Gerudo desert so that might have contributed because there were a few palm fruits in the trees

Comment: No, the palm trees were not picked, so it didn't count. The max limit of dropping items is 10, although you COULD drop it then SUPER QUICKLY pick it back up.

Answer (score 0):

It's also worth noting if the item was originally on the ground (not dropped by a mob) it will not despawn if left there. The same of course is true for items left in chests. I have been utilizing the stamps on the map to abuse this feature. If I see a nice quality weapon or shield but my inventory is full I will simply place the appropriate stamp where I'm standing and come back later when I need it. Of course it's always best if there's a shrine or tower nearby for fast travel.